# File age in Java

Tags: java, file, modulo

I need to find the age of a file based on its name. Alle the files keep to a naming convention like this: DD-MM-YYYY.

I can make a program to come up with the filenames based on how many days/months has passed etc, using the modulus operator, but i can't seem to wrap my head around how to calculate the age from the name. Any tip is welcome.

Any codesamples/ -suggestions should preferable be in Java.

Regards
Martin

Comment: You could extract the date from the part of the file name with the date and parse it with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Store the file creation date and current date in a java.util.Date object and you can then easily subtract the two to know how old the file is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a DateFormat to *parse* a date as well as format one.

Untested:

```
String name = file.getName();
String datePortion = /*extract date portion*/;

DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date fileDate = fmt.parse(datePortion);
long msBetweenDates = new Date().getTime() - fileDate.getTime();
```

How you extract the date portion depends on your file naming scheme, but it's probably as easy as:

```
String datePortion = name.replaceAll(".*((\\d)+-(\\d)+-(\\d)+).*", "$1");
```

Comment: I think i have managed to make it work like this, i just need a way of comparing to six months, since six months in milliseconds become a big number, and kills the interger upperbound.

Comment: @Martin: it might blow an int's bounds, but you'll see I'm using a long which should have no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

if the last modified date is enough, you can use:

```
    File file = new File("C:/file.txt");
    Date date = new Date(file.lastModified());
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not usable since files can be modified all the time, the filter needs to see when they were created. But thanks.